# Is there any way to communicate with the asker of a voluntarily deleted question?

Tags: discussion

There was a question asked a few minutes ago that was not very clear.  I added a comment asking for clarification, but another user followed that up with a comment that might have been perceived as rude.  The comment itself was not constructive (IMO).

After thinking a bit out-of-the-box, imagining the OP intent, I have a possible answer.  But the question has been "voluntarily deleted by the author", I suspect as the result of the second comment.

So my question here:  is there any effective way to communicate with the question author?  If so, how?

I understand that "private messaging" has been discussed before and rejected as a SO feature.  I've not used chat often, so is that a possibility?  Can one invite a specific user to a chat room?

Comment: if you are talking about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554603 i'ts not closed (though I know I'm not answering)

Comment: No, that was my lame attempt to contact the author; I'm sure that is not kosher but it's the only thing I could think of.  So I thought I should ask here for advice.

Comment: Do you mean deleted, not closed? Authors can immediately delete their own (unanswered) questions but they vote to close on their own posts like everyone else (needs 5 votes)

Comment: @BenBrocka  Sorry, yes, I meant "deleted". But in fairness, I was going from memory and thought the message said "closed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're probably referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134712/mysql-how-to-update-a-column-whose-value-depends-on-the-count-of-number-of-ro) (10k) and me as the person who posted the "unconstructive" comment.

I'll stand by that one in this case; though I could maybe have worded it better. This user has a habit of posting questions that show little to no research effort. The full text of the question was (so you can confirm):

> Two columns - A and B. I'd like to update A with the count of rows,
>   whose B value is lesser than the B value of the current column. Is
>   that possible?

To, I hope, prove my point you say *"After thinking a bit out-of-the-box, imagining the OP intent"*. This defeats the objective of an answer. If you have to imagine the OPs intent then you're essentially guessing and the OP has not crafted a very good question. You might be guessing incorrectly. The best possible solution is for the OP to actually demonstrate what they're trying to do and to explain this well.

A user cannot undelete a question they have deleted unless they have 10k reputation or haven't navigated away from the question page. A moderator can see all deleted questions and undelete if requested.

To communicate with them you can post on one of their other posts. I would do this sparingly though.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.  I didn't mean to suggest that your comment was inappropriate.  I don't know the author and don't know why the question was deleted so quickly.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think it was inappropriate @BellevueBob; though as I say I could have worded it better and been more constructive about it. After 95 questions I doubt that I would get through with the "hello and welcome to SO" routine though. The question was deleted by the OP 1 min and 28 seconds after my comment...

Answer (score 2):

No, unless they have contact info in their profile.

You can also comment on any of their other questions or answers, although IMO it's a bit pushy.